# Best wireless solution for 300 user office

Tags: wifi

If you installing wireless in an office of 300 people, and the office has lots of glass meeting rooms what solution would you use for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted possible vendors (Cisco, DLink, 3Com, Xirrus, etc) about site surveys, by chance?

Comment: I'd use a professional installer. See here http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/12/12/a-studied-approach-at-wifi-part-1/ and here http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/picturestory/22-wi-fi-beamforming-networking.html and talk to someone who knows how to do this, since every install is different.

Answer (score 3):

The correct one. Start by measuring the office resistance with testing equipment like a pro installer does.

This REALLY must be tested.